# PyCharm does not support nose-testconfig and I need an alternative

Tags: python, unit-testing, pycharm, nose

I have most of my test cases programmed using nose-testconfig, I'm trying to configure PyCharm in order to have a better IDE to improve my productivity but after investigating a lot an even ask to JetBrains
I discovered PyCharm does not support the nose-testconfig plugin then my ini file cannot be loaded before starting my test, so my test cannot be executed from PyCharm (I tried with external tool configuration but I could neither execute them, apparently same problem with config file `--tc-file=/home/iniFiles/884_firefox.ini"`)

Is there a way to use nose-testconfig with PyCharm? I would like to have testing tool in pycharm, but most important to me is debugging functionality.
I have a huge bunch of legacy test cases which I need to be able to use in PyCharm.

Comment: Requests for external resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow. So I edited that out of your question.

Comment: Ok Louis, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pycharm do support nose-testconfig. It has to be configured in Run->Edit configurations->Defaults->Python tests->Nosetests, check Params check box and set required info there "--tc-file=deafault.ini "